# QPushButton прозрачность

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет. Как сделать кнопку с полупрозрачным фоном и непрозрачными границами?
Пробовал расширить класс QPushButton и переопределить paintEvent(), но тогда и границы (рамка) становится прозрачной, а текст вовсе пропадает

Comment: Используйте стили, познакомиться можно, например, [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/company/istodo/blog/216275/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное есть способ лучше, но я все же напишу как я бы сделал.
Можно сделать прозрачным фон через CSS

```
QString styleButton=QString(
            "QAbstractButton {"
                    "background: rgba(255,255,255,100);"
            "}");
ui->pushButton_2->setStyleSheet(styleButton);
```

Вид кнопки будет не очень красивым поэтому Вам,скорее всего, придется написать свой стиль кнопки для нажатого положения и для отпущенного. Кроме того если фон сделать полностью прозрачным то текст останется, а рамка полностью исчезнет

```
"background: rgba(255,255,255,0);"
```

Приведу небольшой пример кнопки стиля.

```
  QString styleButton=QString(
            "QAbstractButton {"
                    "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                    "border: 2px solid rgb(100,200,200); "
                    "border-radius: 5px;"
                    "background: rgba(100,100,100,100);"
            "}"
            "QAbstractButton:pressed  {"
                    "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                    "border: 4px solid rgb(90,90,90); "
                    "border-radius: 0px;"
                    "background: rgb(110,100,100);"
                    "}");
```